# EMGU CV reassigned image

Tags: c#, opencv, parameters, histogram, emgucv

I try to use two image parameters to control my image in project. The problem is that when I cannot reassign image after applying any public void functions in Emgu CV.
This is my code:

```
public static class Global
{
    public static Image<Gray, byte> xrayPic;
    public static Image<Gray, byte> rootPic;
}

private void takePhotoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageSrc = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(_subPath);
    Image<Gray, Byte> GrayImage = ImageSrc.Convert<Gray, byte>();
    Image<Gray, Byte> MedianImage = GrayImage.SmoothMedian(5);

    Global.xrayPic = MedianImage;
    Global.rootPic = MedianImage;

    Global.xrayPic.Save(_subPath);
    imgBox.Image.Dispose();
    imgBox.Image = Global.xrayPic.Bitmap;    
}

private void checkHistogram_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkHistogram.Checked)
    {
        Image<Gray, byte> tmpPic = Global.xrayPic;
        tmpPic._EqualizeHist();
        // Global.xrayPic._EqualizeHist();
        imgBox.Image.Dispose();
        imgBox.Image = tmpPic.Bitmap;
    }

    if(checkHistogram.Checked == false)
    {
        Global.xrayPic = Global.rootPic;
        imgBox.Image.Dispose();
        imgBox.Image = Global.xrayPic.Bitmap;
    }
}
```

When I check to the checkbox to apply the function __EqualizeHist(), it applied function automatically to adjust first pic to second pic (like attached image). However, when I uncheck, It does not return to my root_Pic (second pic to first pic)
[This is the demonstration for my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ee1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you copy images like this

```
Global.xrayPic = Global.rootPic;
```

then the reference of **Global.rootPic** is copied to **Global.xrayPic** which means both objects will point to the same image in the memory, any changes to either **Global.rootPic** or **Global.xrayPic** will result in change in both.

**Solution:**

Use the deep copy of the images like this

```
Global.xrayPic = Global.rootPic.Clone();
```

If you want to copy emgucv image from 1 variable to another it is always a good idea to **Clone** them.

I hope this will resolve your problem if you have any other problem them copy here.

Comment: my doubt is why? what is the difference between assign a value from one image variable to another one and clone the first one into the second one?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez Assign a value directly does not actually assign the "Value" instead it just copies its address. That's why he needed the deep copy. If you still have doubt then study the concept of shallow and deep copy.

Comment: @NabeelZafar your answer is good enough for me. I do this always but no idea why I have to. Now, I am clear. Thanks.